# xCode - Google Cardboard build failure

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I can build and run my Cardboard app with Unity 5 and xCode 6 and it works great on my iPhone 5.  However, when I hand the project off to another developer he gets the below error when trying to build.  He's using xCode 7 beta and an iPhone 6.  I assume the issue is because he's using xCode 7 beta.  He's added comments within the below log.

```
- Completed reload, in  0.055 seconds
Built-in distortion correction disabled. Causes: [Requires OpenGL]

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)

Built-in UI layer disabled. Causes: [Requires OpenGL]

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)

2015-06-12 15:26:59.290 cardboardTest[12562:2094875] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UnityLandscapeRightOnlyViewController: 0x16e0a090>.
2015-06-12 15:27:07.805 cardboardTest[12562:2094875] Rotation check?! 3
2015-06-12 15:27:10.807 cardboardTest[12562:2094875] popping automatically
2015-06-12 15:27:10.817 cardboardTest[12562:2094875] rotation station

>>>> The below is logged just before the crash, after the stardust finishes circling, after which Aulani video is supposed to start. <<<

Unloading 3 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 10.548125 ms
Built-in distortion correction disabled. Causes: [Requires OpenGL] <<<< OpenGLES.framework is included in the project.

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)

Built-in UI layer disabled. Causes: [Requires OpenGL]

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)


Unloading 25 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 621. <<<< Closed any application running in the background on my iPhone, just to free up available memory. No difference.
Total: 3.234458 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.401500 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.034583 ms MarkObjects: 0.550083 ms  DeleteObjects: 2.247291 ms)
```

#

#

In Unity I have the Graphics API set to Automatic.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I managed to get this to work was to un-tick Automatic graphics API, and to put Metal below OpenGLES2. It seems there's something with the Cardboard SDK that doesn't work with the Metal rendering pipeline.

It's not ideal but it should hopefully get the VR mode working!